# Laravel comment rating

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple comment rating logic now.

For example i have following controller :

```
 public function rating_change(Request $request, Comment $comment)
    {
        if ($request['action'] == 'up') {
            $comment->positive_rating = $comment->positive_rating + 1;
        } else  if ($request['action'] == 'down') {
            $comment->negative_rating = $comment->negative_rating + 1;
        }

        $comment->save();

        return ['positive' => $comment->positive_rating, 'negative' => $comment->negative_rating];
    }
```

And the route for that method:

```
Route::put('/comments_rating/{comment}', function (Comment $comment, Request $request) {
    $commentController = new CommentController();
    return $commentController->rating_change($request, $comment);
});
```

Model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'item_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'item_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Items::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

And resource:

```
return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id'=>$this->user_id,
            'body'=>$this->body,
            //https://github.com/jenssegers/date
            'created_at' => Date::parse($this->created_at)->diffForHumans(),
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at->format('Y-m-d H:i'),
            'author'=>[
                'id'=>$this->author->id,
                'name'=>$this->author->name,
            ],
            'rating'=>[
                'positive'=>$this->positive_rating,
                'negative'=>$this->negative_rating
            ]
        ];
```

The current purpose to prevent change rating by the same user multiple times.(Server side block)
And return the following flag (changed or smth) to frontend.

How should i to do this?

Should i  use the separate table and store all user actions to get flag of changed them in all my comments?

Should i use the https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis for that purpose or sql is enough?

Maybe there is some built in laravel solutions or libraries?

I use laravel sanctum to authorize.

Comment: Your question is off topic, opinion based and asking for recommandations/external resources. one plus, it's well detailed and clear.

Comment: Yes this seems to be opinion based,i just to prefer do not to do the vehicle and found more modern,optimized and clear solution